# Shell script with SFTP and mget finishing before downloads are complete

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, sftp, expect

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/sftp user@place
expect "password:"
send "mysecret\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget dir/*.csv\n";
expect "sftp>"
send "quit\n"
```

It starts to download but after a few seconds, it sends the quit command and exits the program before the downloads are complete.

The only way I've successfully made it stop is to throw in an "interact" command but because I want to run this as a cron job, I don't want to just spawn processes that end up sitting.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

edit:

Someone will ask why I don't have a key setup... this is the only method allowed to me by the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the line set timeout -1 appears to have fixed this problem

The whole script should look as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn /usr/bin/sftp user@place
expect "password:"
send "mysecret\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget dir/*.csv\n";
expect "sftp>"
send "quit\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can use Perl:

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new('user@place', password => 'mysecret');
$sftp->mget("dir/*.csv", '.',
             on_error => sub {
               warn "unable to copy '$_[1]{filename}':".$sftp->error."\n";
             });
```

You will have to install [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign) and [IO::Pty](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aPty) (also available as packages in several linux distributions).